# Building a macro for copying tables from Powerpoint to Excel

Tags: vba, powerpoint, export-to-excel

I'm "very" new at this. I am currently working with a ppt file containing ~120 slides, each containing a table with identical fields but different values.  I want to copy these tables into an Excel file. There is no chart associated with the tables.

I don't care about the field names but just the value and I am looking for a VBA code to do automate this.

Is it even possible or is to too simple. I tried recording a PPT macro for copying the table (alt + t + m + r) but am not sure what to do after that, or how to start an Excel file to paste this macro etc.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all that good with Excel, but perhaps someone else who is can fill in the blanks here.  This is more or less what you'd need to locate the first table on each slide in PowerPoint and do something with it.  Perhaps someone who's good with Excel will fill in the missing bits.

```
Sub CopyTables()

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim lRow As Long

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Set oTbl = GetFirstTable(oSl)
        If oTbl Is Nothing Then
            Exit For
        End If

        With oTbl
            For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                    Debug.Print oTbl.Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                Next
            Next
        End With
    Next

End Sub

Function GetFirstTable(oSl As Slide) As Table
    Dim oSh As Shape
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        If oSh.HasTable Then
            Set GetFirstTable = oSh.Table
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```